# Apple calendar 'wireless' icon next to secondary Gmail account calendars

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I have added my primary Gmail account to Calendar.  This primary account has a few associated calendars associated with it.  On the right hand side of Calendar under the Google heading, my primary Gmail account and its associated calendars appear, but the associated calendars have what looks like a cell phone wifi indicator turned at a 45 degree angle to the right to the right of them.

Any idea what this is?

[image: Gmail associated calendar]

Using Calendar version 6.0 (1648).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates a shared calendar.

Comment: @SebastianSemmier I presumed as much but wasn't able to confirm by searching.  Link to any documentation about this would be appreciated -- there's bound to be more stuff there I am unaware of.  Thanks!